# As adults, is it possible for thoughts to originate from our own thinking?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-modeling

We, as human beings, formulate our own thoughts and notions about everything that we perceive. As we grow up, we acquire knowledge through different means (like parents, teachers, books, movies etc.) which shape our thinking.

My question is that as an adult, if we experience something for the first time - is it possible for us to formulate thoughts about it which originate entirely from our own thinking? If yes, how can we realize it?

Example: While growing up I have seen death in many movies, read about it in many books. But in real life I experienced the death of someone close to me quite recently. I am interested in knowing that is it possible for me to understand it without getting influenced by the knowledge which I already have?

I will be thankful if it is possible to get some pointers regarding the same - how to unlearn everything we know and start afresh.